# error with unicode-math after latest update

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I updated all my miktex packages and now I can't run `unicode-math`. I get a message and I can't seem to debug it. I get the error:

```
("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty")
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           The deprecated command '\luatex_if_engine:T' has ...
l.408 \luatex_if_engine:T
                          { \RequirePackage{unicode-math-luatex} \endinput }
? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

Here is a simple tex file giving the error:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

%%% lipsum
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% FONTS %%%
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

the code in question that gave the error is actually at line 408 of the `unicode-math.sty` file:

```
\luatex_if_engine:T { \RequirePackage{unicode-math-luatex} \endinput }
\xetex_if_engine:T  { \RequirePackage{unicode-math-xetex}  \endinput }
```

Anybody knows what the issue is ?

thanks

Here is the full log from that test file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.5.8)  12 MAY 2017 12:06
entering extended mode
**./unicode.tex
(unicode.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.9t> and hyphenation patterns for 74 language(s) loaded.
("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lipsum\lipsum.sty"
Package: lipsum 2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\c@lips@count=\count87
)
(C:\Users\kdayri\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\unicode-math\unicode-math
.sty
Package: unicode-math 2014/06/30 v0.7f Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 ("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2017/04/01 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
Package: expl3 2017/04/01 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count88
\l_tmpa_int=\count89
\l_tmpb_int=\count90
\g_tmpa_int=\count91
\g_tmpb_int=\count92
\g__prg_map_int=\count93
\c_log_iow=\count94
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count95
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count96
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count97
\l__iow_indent_int=\count98
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count99
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count100
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count108
\l__sort_length_int=\count109
\l__sort_min_int=\count110
\l__sort_top_int=\count111
\l__sort_max_int=\count112
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count113
\l__sort_block_int=\count114
\l__sort_begin_int=\count115
\l__sort_end_int=\count116
\l__sort_A_int=\count117
\l__sort_B_int=\count118
\l__sort_C_int=\count119
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen109
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen114
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen115
\c_empty_coffin=\box32
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box34
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen116
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen118
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_internal_box=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def"
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
\l__driver_tmp_box=\box41
))
("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty"
Package: xparse 2017/04/01 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count120
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count121
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count122
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count123
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count124
)
("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty"
Package: l3keys2e 2017/04/01 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
Package: fontspec 2017/03/31 v2.6a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
Package: fontspec-xetex 2017/03/31 v2.6a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count125
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count126
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count127
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count128
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count129
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count130
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count131
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count132
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1

("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\tuenc.def"
File: tuenc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 472.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 483.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 503.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 523.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setromanfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 543.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 547.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 555.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 563.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 571.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 586.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 603.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 614.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 645.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 672.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 686.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 700.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newICUfeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 720.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 724.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 745.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 778.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 782.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontsExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 786.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \IfFontFeatureActiveTF with sig. 'mmm' on line 797.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCommand with sig. 'mO{}m' on line 3438.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingAccent with sig. 'mm' on line 3444.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingSymbol with sig. 'mm' on line 3450.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingComposite with sig. 'mmm' on line 3456.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCompositeCommand with sig. 'mmm' on line 3462.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareUnicodeEncoding with sig. 'mm' on line 3487.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareSymbol with sig. 'm' on line 3493.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareComposite with sig. 'mm' on line 3501.
.................................................

("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg")
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on inp
```

Comment: works for me with a texlive2017 updated today, show your full log from that test file, do you have an old copy of expl3 in your input path?

Comment: Works fine for me on miktex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: it was working fine for me too before I updated all the packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: installing another tex distribution would be difficult at this point. 
What is expl3? - It's not a package that I currently have installed.

Comment: I did not mean that you should necessarily install, just confirming that it works in the standard distribution and that you (probably) have an old copy, but the log file would confirm, if you added it to your question. You have `expl3` It's a package that you are using any commands using `_` and `:` are defined using that package. eg  syntax such as you show: `\xetex_if_engine:T `

Comment: Then you didn't updated everything. Believe my *my* miktex is really up-to-date. Did you run also the update manager (user)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: yes sorry will edit and add the logs. Indeed I have it. It does not show in the package manager. but it shows in the log:
`("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2017/04/01 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
Package: expl3 2017/04/01 L3 programming layer (code)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I did a Miktex Update and it says no update available. I went into Miktex settings and did Referesh FNDB and Update Formats.

Comment: as predicted you have an ancient local copy in your tex input miktex will have a 2017 unicode-math but you are not using it because you have: 
`(C:\Users\kdayri\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\unicode-math\unicode-math.sty Package: unicode-math 2014/06/30 v0.7f Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX`

Comment: note that all your other files come from `"E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex`

Comment: Perfect: I deleted it and it worked. Thank you. I should clean up the roaming packages. I don't know why they got installed there.

Comment: I don't have miktex but I think that's what @UlrikeFischer meant by `Did you run also the update manager (user)?` you need to use the package manager in admin mode to update `E:\software\MiKTeX 2.9\tex` and in user mode to update `C:\Users\kdayri\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a conflict between the local packages in the roaming profile that were there from a previous installation and the global packages where miktex should be looking. Deleting the roaming packages solves the problem.